# How to get json from php in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have a PHP file. When I send `category:'true'` with the POST method in HTML JS, it gives me back text which I echo in PHP but with React Native it sends me an object instead. How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
return fetch('http://709957ef.ngrok.io/follower/get%20json.php',{
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringfy({
             category:'true'
        })
      })
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responsetxt) => {
          alert(responsetxt)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: are you saying `responsetxt` is an object?

Comment: yes when i alert this android says: [object OBJECT]

Comment: then you just need to access a property on it that's the value you're looking for. Not sure why response.text() returns another promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to and add async to our function.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {

  const response = await fetch('http://709957ef.ngrok.io/follower/get%20json.php',{
    method:'POST',
    body:JSON.stringify({
        category:'true'
    })
  })

  this.setState({
    data: response.text(),
  }, () => console.log('PHP DATA: ', this.state.data))
}
```

Comment: i change my code to : 
----
async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('http://709957ef.ngrok.io/follower/get%20json.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringfy({
        category: 'true'
      })
    })

    return await (response.text());

  }
----
but this code not work and react native warning is: 
"possible unhandled promisw rejection (id:0):typeError:undifined is not a function (evaluting'json.stringfy({
                        category:'true'
})')"

Comment: don't return from there save it in state. please se my updated answer.

Comment: i changed but not back me anything and state was not changed and warning not solve

Comment: what do you get?

Comment: this is picture of warning :
[picture link](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=5647118965&photo_id=501907072981)

Comment: Looks the link is broken

Comment: try it : [picture](https://serving.photos.photobox.com/93425813994d28b6165a8273a379f128c786dbbc8999efffefaab0104b5d8598d240ac0b.jpg)

Comment: you misspelled `JSON.stringfy` change it to `JSON.stringify`

Comment: its not back me text it back [object OBJECT]

Comment: i update code have warning :'json parse error'.and i want text not json

Comment: updated run the code again and tell me what do you get.

Comment: back me 'php data :'